# Microsoft Azure Bot infinitely multiply messages

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

This problem occurs only on Telegram Desktop App for MacOS.

When a user presses one of any "builder.Prompts.choice" buttons, Bot starts sending message, which is supposed to answer user's choice, infinitely.

This problem occured today and there was no any changes in Bot's code or settings in a few days before.

Comment: Have you tested this on other clients? i.e. iOS, windows, Android

Comment: @JasonSowers I tested on iOs, Android, Ubuntu and it's ok. Problem still occurs today on MacOs.

Comment: @JasonSowers also tested on Windows and web-telegram - it's ok.

Comment: What MacOS version are you using (Sierra/High Sierra/El Capitan/etc?), and what Telegram version are you using (2.8? 2.8.2? other?)

Comment: @BlackSeraph Telegram version: 3.8.1.119442, MacOS version: 10.13.3, High Sierra. Also I created a ticket in Azure support and start working on this issue with them.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, this does not appear to be an issue with Bot Framework, but appears to be a bug in the MacOS Telegram client.  I've opened an [issue request  with the Telegram team](https://github.com/overtake/TelegramSwift/issues/135).  I will update this answer when I receive feedback from their team regarding this issue.

Comment: thank you, but this issue appears not only with inline keyboard, in my case it appears also if I press button of "builder.Prompts.choice", as I described earlier.

Comment: You are correct, both are affected.  And as of 4/10/2018, there has been no action or reply by the Telegram maintainers on this issue request I've put in.  Another user has also confirmed that they are also seeing the repeating issue in MacOS's Telegram client as of 4/5/2018.  No updates available as of yet.

Comment: I still have no answer from Telegram team, and you?

Comment: No reply as of yet.  No updates to MacOS X version of Telegram either, at least when I hit Check for Updates.